# Как вставить переменные с массива в запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть массив дат такого вида:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2016-08-08
[1] => 2016-08-15
[2] => 2016-08-15
[3] => 2016-08-22
[4] => 2016-08-22
[5] => 2016-08-29
[6] => 2016-08-29
[7] => 2016-09-05
[8] => 2016-09-05
[9] => 2016-09-12
[10] => 2016-09-12
[11] => 2016-09-19
[12] => 2016-09-19
[13] => 2016-09-26
[14] => 2016-09-26
[15] => 2016-10-03
[16] => 2016-10-03
[17] => 2016-10-10
[18] => 2016-10-10
[19] => 2016-10-17
[20] => 2016-10-17
[21] => 2016-10-24
[22] => 2016-10-24
[23] => 2016-10-31
[24] => 2016-10-31
[25] => 2016-11-07
[26] => 2016-11-07
[27] => 2016-11-14)
```

Есть запрос такого типа:

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE filter1 AND filter2 BETWEEN '{$date_s}' AND '{$date_do}'
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
<?=echo 'Всего: '.$row['txt_tip']?>
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы даты подставлялись попарно в запрос, и выводилось к-во записей согласно к-ву прогонов. Т.е. первая дата с массива - это начало, вторая - конец, третья - начало, четвертая - конец и т.д.

В итоге должны получить что-то типа всего:1, всего:15, всего:... Пробовал через `for` вывести, но как-то громоздко получилось очень и не совсем корректно работало.

Comment: Что в запросе делает filter1?

Comment: могут добавляться разные условия по фильтрам а могут и нет если фильтры невыбраны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = ['2016-08-08', /*etc*/]; //изначальне представление дат
$chunked_dates = array_chunk( $dates, 2 ); //попарно разбиваем даты

$db = new mysqli( /*db connection params */); //подключаемся к бд

//создаём подготовленное выражение
$stmt = $db->prepare(  "SELECT count(*) FROM tables WHERE filter2 BETWEEN ? AND ?" );

//привязаваем переменные к выражению
$from = $to = null;

$stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $from, $to );

foreach( $chunked_dates as list( $from, $to )){
    // для каждой пары дат, выполняем запрос и выводим число строк.
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()['count'];
    echo "от $from до $to всего $count.\n";
}

//закрываем подготовленный запрос
$stmt->close();
```

Для краткости пропустил проверки возвращаемых значенй.

Дополнение:

stmt->bind_param является side effect функцией. Она привязывает ссылки на переменные к подготовленному выражению.

Для работы в функционльном стиле, могу предложить 2 варианта: ограничить этот side effect, либо вообще от него избавится.

Вариант с ограничением, это перенести bind_param внутрь цикла и в конце каждой итерации отвязывать параметры:

```
foreach( $chunked_dates as list( $from, $to )){
     $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $from, $to );
     $stmt->execute();
     $count = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()['count'];
     echo "от $from до $to всего $count.\n";
     $stmt->reset();
}
```

Второй вариант это отказ от подготовленных выражений и формарование запроса вручную для кадой пары дат, но тогда нужно заранее обезопасить параметры.

```
$dates = array_map( [ $db, 'real_escape_string' ], $dates );
//rest of code
foreach( $chunked_dates as list( $from, $to ) ){
     $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM tables WHERE filter2 BETWEEN $from and $to";
     //execute query and print result
}
```

Второй вариант проще перенести в функциональный стиль, но он дат дополнительную нагруску на php (повториное интерполерование строк) и на БД (каждый раз нужно заново парсить sql).

Comment: а как сделать это: `//привязаваем переменные к выражению
$from = $to = null;
$stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $from, $to );` порсто весь код у меня в функционалке остальное более менее понятно как переделать под функцимонал а как это сделать не пойму

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Как это делается по-человечески

```
SELECT min(filter2) week, count(*) cnt FROM tables 
    WHERE filter1 AND filter2 BETWEEN '2016-08-08' AND '2016-11-14'
    GROUP BY date_format(filter1, "%Y-%u")
```

(здесь предполагается, что даты не накладываются друг на друга, в отличие от условий, изложенных в вопросе)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем корректный вид данных на входе, можно легко ошибится, правильнее иметь что-то такое:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2016-08-08
            [to] => 2016-08-15
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2016-08-15
            [to] => 2016-08-22
        )
...
)
```

В вашем случае я бы сделал так

```
for ($i=0, $k = count($d); $i < $k; $i=$i+2) {
    echo "from ".$d[$i]." to ".$d[$i+1]."\n";
}
```

Результат

```
from 2016-08-08 to 2016-08-15
from 2016-08-15 to 2016-08-22
from 2016-08-22 to 2016-08-29
from 2016-08-29 to 2016-09-05
from 2016-09-05 to 2016-09-12
from 2016-09-12 to 2016-09-19
from 2016-09-19 to 2016-09-26
from 2016-09-26 to 2016-10-03
from 2016-10-03 to 2016-10-10
from 2016-10-10 to 2016-10-17
from 2016-10-17 to 2016-10-24
from 2016-10-24 to 2016-10-31
from 2016-10-31 to 2016-11-07
from 2016-11-07 to 2016-11-14
```